# Userfrosting calling model from template twig

Tags: twig, userfrosting

For the first time, I am working on userfrosting, it is based on MVC. So I know how the things are working but my issue is now, I want to call the one of the model to find the particular userid ie. `Employee::find(1)`

I want to get the `username` for the particular id, as I am running a for loop to I will be getting different id.

How can I call the model in my template twig?

Comment: pass the object to twig and call the appropiate getter

Comment: I don't completely understand your question.  Are you trying to work with just one particular `Employee` in your template, or a whole collection of `Employee`s?

Comment: suppose , I am querying select * from user  and I am getting 5 rows in an array , so using for loop I am showing the data in table format and getting the userid which is related to employee table , so I want to use Employee::find(1) in template

Comment: What code you have now, how you render the template?

Comment: It sounds like you want to load the related user *along with each employee* in your controller, then pass that whole collection to your template.  If each `Employee` has exactly one `User` associated with it, then your Employee model needs a `hasOne` relationship.  See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Please edit your question explain *exactly* what you want to do, and I can try to write up a complete answer.